# Unity2D: Add text to rigidbody2D element

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, rigid-bodies, guitext

I'm new to Unity and I started with the [Catch Game Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/2d-catch-game-pt2?playlist=17093) to learn to create a 2D game. Everything is working now but for my needs, I would like to **add different textboxes to each of the fallen elements** (in the tutorial the bowling balls) Those texts should move with the objects. I know I can change text dynamically in the code, but I couldn't figure out how to correctly add the element.

I tried to add a text object as a child of the gameobject and also tried to create a new gameobject which contains a text, but I can't position the element in front of the background and above my wished element (I can't choose a sorting layer for this)

Imagine this is the object which has to be collected and I would like to show a text like this:

[image]

My Questions are:

**1. How can I add a text to be displayed in the correct position (GUIText, text in a gameobject, only text or something else?**

**2. How can I make this text dynamically move with the fallen object?**

**3. Can I set a background to my text as displayed above?**

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem and did the following thing:

1. I created a Sprite with my wished background (black rectangle) and added it to the scene
2. I created a 3D Text and added it as a child to the created Sprite (and scaled it and positioned it)
3. I added a Script to the 3d Text with the following content:

   ```
   void Start () {
       this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingLayerName = "[MyLayerName]";
       this.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sortingOrder = 3;
   }
   ```
4. I added the Sprite (with the text as child) to my gameObject (ananas)
5. A renewed the object in the Prefabs folder

Maybe my solution helps other people facing a similar problem.